# Can't save Magento 1 backend system settings

Tags: database, magento, settings, backend, admin

I'm unable to save Magento backend settings under 'System'. I do get a 'The configuration has been saved.' message but the actual changes are reverted back to their previous state. It is possible to change (for example) an emailadress in the database and these changes do show. But our customer should be able to do these changes himself in the Magento backend panel.

I can't see anything out of the ordinary in the logs.

I'm running Magento 1.9.3.6.

Answer (score 1):

It could be an issue with PHP's max_input_vars setting.

try changing this to something higher

https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars